# Pausing Streaming RTMFP

Tags: video, actionscript, streaming, rtmfp

I have an app that streams in video live, and archives it as it goes along.

My question is this:  What happens when I hit, or allow, 'pause' on a live stream, and then 'play'?  Obviously the person on the other end streaming continues to do so, and my application continues to archive it, but what about the person receiving the stream?

Do they resume play from the archived copy, or do they seek ahead to the current point in the stream, missing everything they were paused for?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't pause a live stream. If a live stream is paused on resume it should start playing from the current stream. Failing that, disabling the pause feature would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out http://www.veetle.com. It is all live steams and they do not have a pause button but rather an on and off button.

So to answer your question I would say to make it simple pause should stop/pause the playback and then when it is resumed start from where the live stream is.

On the other hand if you could pause the live stream and continue from the same time that would be really slick, a little confusing to build but slick